# Ansible 'ping' fail - 'session request sent', but 'read header failed: Broken pipe'

Tags: networking, ssh, ansible

I'm a newbie at Ansible and my goal is use this tool to configure Moxa switches by SSH interface. I'm able to connect via SSH from my Ubuntu PC without problems:

```bash
admin@192.168.127.254's password:

Please change default password in consideration of higher security level.

                    MOXA EDR-810 Series   V5.12.9 build 22052312.               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Firewall/VPN Router 04106# quit
Firewall/VPN Router 04106# Connection to 192.168.127.254 closed.
```

however after I send a ping message like this

```bash
ansible all -m ping
```

I receive this error message

```bash
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/rodrigo/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) [GCC 9.4.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
META: ran handlers
<192.168.127.254> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<192.168.127.254> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d11 ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="admin"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/rodrigo/.ansible/cp/f1d5153c55 192.168.127.254 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~admin && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.127.254> (255, b'', b'OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020\r\n
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\n
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files\r\n
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *\r\n
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.127.254 is address\r\n
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\n
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\n
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\n
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\n
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\n
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 1118\r\n
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\n
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\n
debug2: Control master terminated unexpectedly\r\n')
192.168.127.254 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020\r\n
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\n
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files\r\n
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *\r\n
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.127.254 is address\r\n
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\n
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\n
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\n
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\n
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\n
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 1118\r\n
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\n
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\n
debug2: Control master terminated unexpectedly",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

SO: Ubuntu Server 20

Regards

Comment: You have the ssh command line in the verbose output. Run it manually and remove parameters one by one until you find the one that causes the problem. The sshd log on the server side could also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According the output provided it seems that you try to establish a SSH connection to a switch. Such devices may not have all capabilities for Python scripts.

Because of [`ping` module – Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong on success](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html) it "*is NOT ICMP ping, ... just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node*".

Furthermore, to do so, Ansible tries to run `/bin/sh -c` on the Remote Node which also might not be possible on your target.

In other words, Ansible is not only SSHing into the Target Node, but performing additional tasks which might going to fail in your case.

You may need to address this by using specific custom or community modules for your MOXA EDR-810 Series Firewall VPN Router, utilize REST API interfaces or use the not recommended [`raw` module – Executes a low-down and dirty command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/raw_module.html)

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to check SSH access?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647690/6771046)
- [Ansible: Error "Line has invalid autocommand"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73651902/6771046)
- [Whats the difference between ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817243/6771046)